# SASS inserts code comments periodically into my compiled CSS

Tags: css, compiler-construction, sass, stylesheet, css-frameworks

just wondering why SASS does this and how to prevent it - I'm using Scout to manage all my Sass / Compass projects. Inside a "sass" folder I have a main.scss file which imports a partials/reset.scss file. These compile to ../css/main.css and ../css/partials/reset.css respectively. But in both of the compiled CSS files, there are periodic comments like this:

```
/* line 13, ../../sass/partials/reset.scss */

/* line 24, ../../sass/partials/reset.scss */
```

How do I prevent it from adding these comments? They're not in the scss files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are line comments that indicate where the code that generates those styles comes from.  You can disable it by uncommenting out this line in your config.rb:

```
# line_comments = false
```