# Compass: how to remove comments containing path to a package scss from generated css file?

Tags: css, version-control, sass, compass-sass

We use compass in our project. It generates some css files, which look like this on my colleague's machine:

```
/* line 22, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
html {
  line-height: 1; }

/* line 24, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

/* line 10, ../sass/partials/dependencies/font-awesome/_larger.scss */
.fa-2x {
  font-size: 2em; }
```

But sometimes I have to update CSS by myself. I edit the corresponding sass file and run `compass compile`. It regenerates CSS successfully, but half of comments are changed:

```
/* line 22, C:/Soft/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
html {
  line-height: 1; }

/* line 24, C:/Soft/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

/* line 10, ../sass/partials/dependencies/font-awesome/_larger.scss */
.fa-2x {
  font-size: 2em; }
```

Here's the problem: we store this CSS in a VCS, as not everyone in our team has Ruby and Compass installed. And each commit modifying one line in SASS expands to a thousand-line commit which changes comments (because we have compass installed in different directories).

Is there any way to prevent compass from adding comments about frameworks? I want to keep comments about SCSS coming from the project, but I want to get rid of comments that come from frameworks lying in a machine-specific place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS inserts code comments periodically into my compiled CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548458/sass-inserts-code-comments-periodically-into-my-compiled-css)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I want to keep one kind of comments (project-specific) and get rid of another (framework-specific).

Answer (score 4):

This can be changed in config.rb

```
line_comments = false
```

Comment: Won't it remove all comments, not only the ones that come from frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
line_comments = false
```

to my config/compass.rb to remove all of the line comments from the compiled stylesheets.