# SASS adds comments to CSS

Tags: sass, comments

Hi i don't know why SASS compiles comments like /* line 3, ../sass/style.scss */

Any thoughts?

**SCSS CODE**

```
@import 'compass/css3';

nav{
  background: #e25555;
  ul{
      @include box-sizing(border-box);
  }
}
```

**COMPILED CSS**

```
/* line 3, ../sass/style.scss */
nav {
  background: #e25555;
}
/* line 5, ../sass/style.scss */
nav ul {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compass: how to remove comments containing path to a package scss from generated css file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161219/compass-how-to-remove-comments-containing-path-to-a-package-scss-from-generated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments show where in your source files the sass that generates the following block is located, making it easier for a developer/maintainer to see where they should edit the sass to make the changes they want.

In a production environment, the .css file would typically be minified and would not include these comments. If you are using Compass to compile your sass to css, you can change this setting in your config.rb file. You can either turn off just the line comments by setting

```
line_comments = false
```

(possibly by uncommenting that line in your current config.rb), or you can minify your css by setting

```
output_style = :compressed
```